# play framework commands on ubuntu stopped working after updating packages on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, playframework

Has anyone else come across this at all?  I used to be able to run play (v.1.2.3) commands in the command prompt using "play run" but now am unable to do so.  Now I get the following error (after having updated ubuntu packages):

play FAIL formats: can't open input file

I am guessing one way would be to simply change the location of the play directory location in the path (to prepend as opposed to append) - any other suggestions (specially to avoid this going forward).

Comment: This appears off-topic for Stack Overflow. It's too vague to be a real question on SU or U&L, so it probably shouldn't be migrated without heavy editing.

Comment: fyi - prepending the path with the play framework directory location solved the problem.  I am just wondering now if there is a better way of handling this - specially going forward.

Comment: this was a valid question - if you do not consider it as a valid one, actually write out the reason instead of making vague comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prepending (as opposed to appending) the path with the play framework directory location solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put the play-framework executable earlier in your PATH.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and you likely will see the SoX path show up before the play-framework path. You are probably "appending" the play framework path to your $PATH in .bashrc. Try "prepending" it.

```
export PATH=${PLAY_FRAMEWORK}:$PATH
```

or something to that extent. This is pretty standard unix/windows/mac path stuff.

Reference Google Groups discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/yBjwFhJjSvY)